# Hiding fields within Access report if certain field is Null-Access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I am trying to hide labels and my text boxes for a certain section of my report if there is a specific field that is null. for example, I have staff that works weekdays and or weekends but don't work weekends. I don't want weekend info to show on the report if you are only working weekdays. this also includes the labels associated with it.

Comment: This code needs to be in the `On Format` event.

Comment: this is the code I have but I believe it wont work because there referenced field is text and not a number..                                                             
    Me.EarlyVotingHeader.Visible = Me.[EV Role].Value
    Me.EarlyVotingHeader.Visible = Me.EarlyVotingHeader.Visible

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: EarlyVotingHeader is a textbox you want to hide? [EV Role] Is textbox that could be Null? What event is code in? `Me.EarlyVotingHeader.Visible = Not IsNull(Me.[EV Role])`

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach. abstract any calculations involved in calculating who works weekends to a set of public functions in a code module.  You can refer to public functions inside a code module almost anywhere in Access.Then in either the report open event or the report load event, set the controls you don't want to show to be invisible.  for instance:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private iworksweekends As Boolean
Public Function SetWorksWeekends(value As Boolean) As Boolean
iworksweekends = value
End Function
Public Function GetWorksWeekends(employeename As String) As Boolean
GetWorksWeekends = iworksweekends
End Function
Public Sub RandomlySetWorksWeekends(employeename As String)
If Rnd > 0.5 Then
iworksweekends = True
Else
iworksweekends = False
End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
RandomlySetWorksWeekends 'realistic?
If GetWorksWeekends Then
Me.txtAge.Visible = False
Me.txtDate.Visible = False
Me.txtTime.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

One advantage of affectively adding properties to your database like this is code reuse.  Once you have more than one version of a report Murphy says you will likely need the inconvenient version.  Multiple parameters and multiple reports?  You will probably want a form for customizing the reports.  With properties you don't have to bother passing and parsing parameters between forms or far worse referring to controls between forms and reports.  Here is one rather random example of creating a report based on criteria: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tguyxbpOXp0

edit: Access does have traditional data based conditional formatting.  Conditional formatting in Access is done by selecting the control and selecting format on the ribbon.  In Access 2016 you can only change the color or outline of the control.  Excel has better conditional formatting options so I recommend exporting the report to Excel when data based formatting is needed.